# Open balls contained within each other - proof

Tags: general-topology

Within a larger proof, I am trying to show that $B_d(x,s_1)\subseteq{B_{{\varrho}_{ort}}(x,r)}$ where $d$ is the Euclidean metric and $\varrho_{ort}$ is the orthogonal metric. So, I want:

$\sqrt[]{(x_1-x_1')^2+...+(x_n-x_n')^2}<s_1\rightarrow|x_1-x_1'|+...+|x_n-x_n'|<r$

for some $s_1>0$ and all $r>0$.

Comment: Hint: do it for the unit ball and in dimension 2 to get an idea on how you should proceed in the general case.

Comment: I was with you right up to "and all $r > 0$", so if you constrain the sum of the absolute values to be less than all positive numbers, then it must be no more than 0. Since it's a sum of nonnegatives, it must be EQUAL to 0, adn that constrains $x$ to be $x'$.

Comment: You might want to try if for the case $n = 1$ as well as the $n = 2, 3$ cases suggested by @EduardoLonga.

Comment: I think you mean to show that for a given $r>0$, there exists an $s_1>0$ with this property. If this property is true for $s_1$, then of course it it true for all $s<s_1$.

Answer (score 0):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2425854/4280) I show (generalising from the $2$ dimensions there to $n$ here) that

$$d(x,y) \le \sqrt{n}\rho_{\text{ort}}(x,y)$$ and

$$\rho_{\text{ort}}(x,y) \le nd(x,y)$$

for all vectors $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

This will help in picking the right $s_1$ for every $r>0$, namely $s_1 = \frac{r}{n}$